# Não redireciona

Tags: php, header

Tenho o código abaixo logo na entrada de uma página. Estou indo para ela sem passar ID pelo GET, então está entrando no ELSE corretamente. Está passando pelo setFlash, mas não redireciona a página através do location. Se mantém na mesma página. O que pode ser?

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $estabelecimentoDao = new EstabelecimentoDAO(); 
        $estabelecimentos = $estabelecimentoDao->all(); 
        $agendaDao = new AgendaDAO();
        $teste = $agendaDao->first($id);
    }else{
        $flash = new Flash();
        $flash->setFlash('Para editar você precisa passar um ID Válido</br>', 'alert-danger');
        header('Location:../../View/Agenda/index.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: esse código é inserindo em uma página maior? digo o header já foi enviado? acredito que só possa fazer redirecionamentos antes de enviar o header

Comment: header não vai funcionar se você tiver qualquer código impresso na tela.

Comment: Era isto mesmo. Obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação do PHP:

> Lembre-se que o header() precisa ser chamado antes que qualquer conteúdo
>   seja enviado, seja por tags HTML, linhas em branco em um arquivo ou do próprio PHP.

Sendo assim, não faça alertas na tela, pois o header não irá funcionar.